# How can I get base64 of a gif image frame with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, base64, frame, gif, animated-gif

I would like to get the base64 code of a gif image from the internet.
The base64 should be generated from the first frame of the gif image.

I'm able to store the first frame of a gif image with the following code in nodejs:

```
var gifFrames = require('gif-frames');
var fs = require('fs');
 
gifFrames({ url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif', frames: 0 }).then(function (frameData) {
  frameData[0].getImage().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('firstframe.jpg'));
});
```

I now need the base64 code of this stored jpg image.
Ideally the image will not be stored on the disk and just prints the base64 code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since `getImage()` returns a `ContentStream`, you just need to read the `Buffer` and convert it to Base64. Somehow like this:

```
var gifFrames = require('gif-frames');
var fs = require('fs');

gifFrames({
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif',
    frames: 0
}).then(function (frameData) {
    var stream = frameData[0].getImage(),
    b64 = stream.read().toString('base64');

    console.log(b64);
});
```